# Método POST Jquery e PHP

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Caros colegas.

Tenho um botão no bootstrap:

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary active" name="Botao" value="Ativar" id="ativar">Ativar</button>
```

Gostaria que ao clicar nesse botão, o status fosse mudado para **Desativar**, mas sem dar refresh na página. Estou usando o código abaixo para direcionar para a página que faz a alteração, porém parece que não está indo. Veja:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ativar').click(function() {
    var valor = $(this).attr('value');
     $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "alterar.php?Key="+valor,
             data:  datastring
      })
    });
  });
```

A alteração no PHP está OK quando vou direto na página alterar.php, porém pelo botão parece que não está enxergando a página.

Comment: Recomendo a leitura de http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ parte de `success`.

Comment: Em que página está a correr esse JavaScript? queres mudar o _status_ na mesma página ou em futuras páginas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ARQUIVO JS

var valor = jQuery('button.active').val();

jQuery.ajax({
    url : "alterar.php?Key="+valor,
    dataType : 'json',
    async : false,
    success : function(msg) {
        if(msg.status == 1){
            jQuery('button.active').html('Ativo').val('Ativo');
        }else{
            jQuery('button.active').html('Desativado').val('Desativado');
        }
    }
});

Arquivo PHP

$return = array('status'=>null);
if($_GET['Key'] == 'Ativo'){
    $return['status'] = 0;
}else{
    $return['status'] = 1;
}

die(json_encode($return));
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos os colegas que ajudaram. No botão, para passar o ID do usuário, usei dessa forma: value="<?php echo $idUsuarios; ?>". Assim peguei o valor do ID passado pelo botão.

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#ativar').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var valor = $(this).attr('value');
             $.ajax ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "alterar.php",
                    data: {key: valor},
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result) {
                 }
              })
            });
          });
```